# Page loader in AJAX behaves differently on the same page

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I am calling a loader before the ajax call on my page like below

```
    $('#firstbutton').click(function() {
      $('body').addClass('loading');
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "somepage.htm",
        async: false,
        success: function() {
          //some code
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
        error: function(error) {
           //error handling
        }
      });
    });

    $('#secondbutton').click(function() {
      $('body').addClass('loading');
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "somepage2.htm",
        async: false,
        success: function() {
          //some code
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
        error: function(error) {
           //error handling
        }
      });
    });
```

All this is in a separate js file. When I click the first button(#button), the loader shows and is hidden once the call is done and result is shown but when i click on the second button(#anotherbutton), the loader doesn't show up but the result gets displayed after sometime. Also this same set of code works perfectly fine in firefox. I'm new to ajax so it's hard for me to debug. Any help is appreciated.

Accompanying HTML

```
<div class="tab-slider-nav">
    <ul class="tab-slider-tabs">
        <li class="tab-slider-trigger active>tab with #button</li>
        <li class="tab-slider-trigger">tab with #anotherbutton</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-body">
        <p>Tab with #firstbutton</p>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="button">
           <a id="firstbutton" class="btn">transfer</a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="tab2" class="tab-body">
        <p>Tab with #secondbutton</p>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="button">
           <a id="secondbutton" class="btn">transfer</a>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="loadingModal">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Loader CSS

```
    .loadingModal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1000;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8);
    }

    .loadingModal ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
    }

    .loadingModal ul li {
        list-style: none;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        background: #1c1d4c;
        margin: 0 5px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
        -o-animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite; 
        animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes animate {
        0% {
           transform: translateY(0);
        }
        60% {
           transform: translateY(0);
        }
        80% {
           transform: translateY(-40px);
        }
        100% {
           transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }

    .loadingModal ul li:nth-child(1) {
        animation-delay: 0s;
    }

    .loadingModal ul li:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: -1.2s;
    }

    .loadingModal ul li:nth-child(3) {
       animation-delay: -1s;
    }

    .loadingModal ul li:nth-child(4) {
       animation-delay: -.8s;
    }

    .loadingModal ul li:nth-child(5) {
         animation-delay: -.6s;
    }

    body.loading .loadingModal {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: You have a bunch of duplicate IDs. IDs are required to be unique, and an ID selector will only match the first one.

Comment: The sample code has multiple `id="button"`. Maybe the real code also has duplicate `id="anotherbutton"`.

Comment: Sorry it's actually class="button", i was typing the entire code out. But i changed it and still have the same issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you're actually doing. It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong when we can't see the actual code.

Comment: BTW, you should stop using `async: false`. Synchronous AJAX is deprecated.

Comment: You give id to <a> tag so please use preventDefault on click or change event and add href = "#" in <a> tag.

Comment: @Barmar sorry since I can't put the code exactly as it is, I had to put up just the main parts. I have made the ids and classes unique as per the suggestions. The main problem I'm facing is that I know the loader is working but it's behaviour is not consistent (it's working perfectly fine in Firefox throughout the application whereas in chrome it works in one place but not in another)

Comment: @Barmar I have a page which has two tabs and each tab has a button. When I click on the buttons some AJAX calls will be made and data will be returned and displayed but since it takes time I placed the loader before the AJAX calls and removed them on success. This works with the button in the first tab but it doesn't work with button in the second tab. Hope this clears up some confusion.

Comment: That's exactly what I understood you to be saying. I understand the problem you're having, but without seeing the actual code how can we figure out why it's happening? Have you tried using the browser's debugger to step through the code?

Comment: I removed the `async: false` part and now my loader shows up. Maybe it didn't work because I was using some deprecated values? 
Thanks everyone! Highly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You just try with

1)

```
 // change for both click 
 $(document).on('click','#anotherbutton',function(){
    // code
 });
```

2)

Add '.complete' state in ajax call and remove removeClass code from success and add in to '.complete' state

Comment: Changed but still have the same issue

Comment: can you please give unique and valid name to your id or class . you given 3 times same id .

Comment: I have changed the ids and classes

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer as per OP's edits.
Multiple fixes were needed after the updation :
1)Anchor tag has it's own action, hence any separate event handler associated with it needs a `preventDefault()` to work.
2) Async false is deprecated, so you have to remove the same from your code.

```js
 $('#firstbutton').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('body').addClass('loading');
      $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        success: function() {
          //some code
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
        error: function(error) {
           //error handling
        }
      });
    });

    $('#secondbutton').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
      $('body').addClass('loading');
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        success: function() {
          //some code
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
        error: function(error) {
           //error handling
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
.loadingModal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1000;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8);
    }

    .loadingModal ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
    }

    .loadingModal ul li {
        list-style: none;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        background: #1c1d4c;
        margin: 0 5px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
        -o-animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite; 
        animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes animate {
        0% {
           transform: translateY(0);
        }
        60% {
           transform: translateY(0);
        }
        80% {
           transform: translateY(-40px);
        }
        100% {
           transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }

    .loadingModal ul li:nth-child(1) {
        animation-delay: 0s;
    }

    .loadingModal ul li:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: -1.2s;
    }

    .loadingModal ul li:nth-child(3) {
       animation-delay: -1s;
    }

    .loadingModal ul li:nth-child(4) {
       animation-delay: -.8s;
    }

    .loadingModal ul li:nth-child(5) {
         animation-delay: -.6s;
    }

    body.loading .loadingModal {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="tab-slider-nav">
    <ul class="tab-slider-tabs">
        <li class="tab-slider-trigger active">tab with #button</li>
        <li class="tab-slider-trigger">tab with #anotherbutton</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-body">
        <p>Tab with #firstbutton</p>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="button">
           <a id="firstbutton" class="btn">transfer</a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="tab2" class="tab-body">
        <p>Tab with #secondbutton</p>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="button">
           <a id="secondbutton" class="btn">transfer</a>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="loadingModal">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="loadingModal">loader</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You have three `id="button"` elements. See the fixes he made to the HTML in the question.

Comment: @Barmar Updated the answer .